# Is there any way of using 'in' keyword in 'eval' function in drl file of drools

Tags: drools

I want use the 'in' keyword in 'eval' function in which I am getting error that 'in' is not recognized by drools. So I have multiple values which I want check against a particular fact's attribute

```
when
    $person : Person(PIN in ("123","456","789"))
then
    //do something
end
```

//Like this I want use it in eval

```
when
    $person : Person()
    eval($person.PIN in ("123","456","789"))
then
    //do something
end
```

But it is showing compile time error.
is there any other way to do it.

*Edited*

So I have some conditions in Decision Table where I want to use eval because other ways are not helpful in my scenario, below snapshot will Explain

[SnapShot 1: Decision Table without eval()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhx4H.png)

[SnapShot 2: Decision Table with eval()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8w7.png)

1. Issue in first snapshot:
   When compiling the spreadsheet the condition goes to the second lines object like below code : this is how it gets interpreted

```
when
   personMap : PersonMap ()
   basicEligiblePerson : Person( personalAddress.PIN in ($param) ) from 
   personMap.AddressesList
   addresses : Address() from basicEligiblePerson.AddressesList
   personalAddress : PersonalAddress() from addresses.PersonalAddress
then
   basicEligiblePerson.setEligibility(true);
end
```

2. Issue in second snapshot : 
   When compiling this spreadsheet the condition goes to eval() function but 'in' keyword does not work in eval().

```
when
   personMap : PersonMap ()
   basicEligiblePerson : Person( personalAddress.PIN in ($param) ) from 
   personMap.AddressesList
   addresses : Address() from basicEligiblePerson.AddressesList
   personalAddress : PersonalAddress() from addresses.PersonalAddress
   eval( personalAddress.PIN in ($param) )
then
   basicEligiblePerson.setEligibility(true);
end
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

First sample given in your question is sufficient for the validation. You don't need to use eval.

```
when
    $person : Person(PIN in ("123","456","789"))
then
    //do something
end
```

If your requirement is to set eligibility to true for a given set of PINs, then you don't really need a decision table. I don't completely understand your POJO structure, so if Person class has a member variable addressList and AddressList class has a member personalAddress which has the member variable pin, you can achieve the results using the following rule. Please note that the nested fields are referred using the member variable names, not the class names. Also when you access the nested elements, if any of the elements can be null, please add the null check as well to avoid null pointer exceptions.

```
when
   $basicEligiblePerson : Person( addressesList.personalAddress.pin in ("1234", "4567") ) 
then
   $basicEligiblePerson.setEligibility(true);
end
```

Comment: Yes please don't use eval. You shouldn't use eval.

Comment: The above given is just an small example of what I am doing. but the actual work is pretty big. so I must use decision table.(and it a requirement also)